# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 stForm = new Form1();
        DialogResult result = stForm.ShowDialog(this);

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        Inscrierea__pentru_burs_sau_contract media = new Inscrierea__pentru_burs_sau_contract();
        media.Media_MNDP = stForm.MNDP.Text;
        media.Media_MNEA = stForm.MNEA.Text;
        media.Media_Concurs = stForm.MediaConcurs.Text;

        db.Media.Add(media);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Salvarea a avut loc cu succes!!!");
    }
```

### Please help me with my error at line with:

1. media.Media_MNDP = stForm.MNDP.Text;
2. media.Media_MNEA = stForm.MNEA.Text;
3. media.Media_Concurs = stForm.MediaConcurs.Text;

error" Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'"

Comment: Not sure if its simply for demonstration purpose, if not be informed that you should not have classes named like 'form1' and stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make use of `Decimal.TryParse(string, out val)`

Example :

```
decimal val;
if(Decimal.TryParse(stForm.MNDP.Text, out val))
    media.Media_MNDP = val;
```

better to use tryparse method because it avoid runtime exception to be thrown

Comment: Yes i'd alaways use this, especially when dealing with user interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 media.Media_MNDP = Decimal.Parse(stForm.MNDP.Text);
```

For emtpy textbox that will throw error .

To make error free try this

```
decimal demo;

if(Decimal.TryParse(stForm.MNDP.Text,out demo)){
  media.Media_MNDP = Decimal.Parse(stForm.MNDP.Text);
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `Decimal.Parse(text)`, the variable `demo` has already the right value. See [Pranay Rana's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30210991/2029849)

Answer (score 1):

Add try-catch when use Parse

```
try{
media.Media_MNDP = Decimal.Parse(stForm.MNDP.Text);
media.Media_MNEA = Decimal.Parse(stForm.MNEA.Text);
media.Media_Concurs = Decimal.Parse(stForm.MediaConcurs.Text);
}
catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Comment: incorrect. bad usage. use TryParse. At this point in your code, any one of them can throw an Exception...but which one? you wont be able to figure it out during runtime.

Comment: Similar maybe but not the same. Tryparse takes away the bloated code you have written. why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: The question is "convert type 'string' to 'decimal' ". My solution works

Comment: @ANguyen just because a solution works doesn't mean it is a good approach to that solution.

Comment: the first comment is "incorrect". How it is incorrect? It may not be the best but it's not incorrect.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach. What if you don't care which Parse failed? You may need to know if a exception happen, not the exception.